# How to check if key present in nested json in c++ using nlohmann

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have a below json data:

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "candidates": [
                {
                    "confidence": 0.80836,
                    "enrollment_timestamp": "20190613123728",
                    "face_id": "871b7d6e8bb6439a827",
                    "subject_id": "1"
                }
            ],
            "transaction": {
                "confidence": 0.80836,
                "enrollment_timestamp": "20190613123728",
                "eyeDistance": 111,
                "face_id": "871b7d6e8bb6439a827",
                "gallery_name": "development",
                "height": 325,
                "pitch": 8,
                "quality": -4,
                "roll": 3,
                "status": "success",
                "subject_id": "1",
                "topLeftX": 21,
                "topLeftY": 36,
                "width": 263,
                "yaw": -34
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to check if `subject_id` is present in the above json data or not. For this I did below:

```
auto subjectIdIter = response.find("subject_id");
if (subjectIdIter != response.end())
{
    cout << "it is found" << endl;

}
else
{
    cout << "not found " << endl;
}
```

How can I resolve this. Thanks

Answer (score 24):

There is a member function [`contains`](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a0a45fc740637123fdf05fef970f8be47.html#a0a45fc740637123fdf05fef970f8be47) that returns a `bool` indicating whether a given key exists in the JSON value.

Instead of

```
auto subjectIdIter = response.find("subject_id");
if (subjectIdIter != response.end())
{
    cout << "it is found" << endl;

}
else
{
    cout << "not found " << endl;
}
```

You could write:

```
if (response.contains("subject_id"))
{
    cout << "it is found" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "not found " << endl;
}
```

Comment: This comment is the most up-to-date answer.

Comment: It did not work for me. No member named contains

Comment: Then you are using a very old version.

Answer (score 1):

use find including images and candidates and check:

```
if (response["images"]["candidates"].find("subject_id") != 
           response["images"]["candidates"].end())
```

Comment: why `response["images"]["candidates"].end())` why not simply use `response.end()`

Comment: why? because the developer who wrote the code suggest it : https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/1000#issuecomment-371760982

Answer (score 1):

Candidates is an array, so you just need to iterate the objects and call find.

```
bool found = false;
for( auto c: response.at("images").at("candidates") ) {
    if( c.find("subject_id") != c.end() ) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```